Sorting 2D points clockwise
I found a way to sort clockwise 2D points in Unity, but for some reason that i don't understand there are sometimes points still in the wrong order.
On the first picture the red sphere is the center and the other spheres are colored by order.
The second picture shown the position of those spheres with wrong order.


  private static Vector2[] SortClockwise(List<Vector2> vertices)
  {
      // calculate center
      Vector2 center = Vector2.zero;
      for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count; i++)
      {
          center += vertices[i];
      }
      center /= vertices.Count;

      // order by the angle to center
      return vertices.OrderBy(point => Math.Atan2(point.x - center.x, point.y - center.y)).ToArray();
  }

Edit:
Top left corner (red: current index, blue lines: expectation)

I understand the concave problem now and from my understanding i can assume that all convex polygons are in the right order but concave will be false?
If i take picture 2 for example and check for concave polygons and swap position if it is concave (depending i know which positions to swap)? or will there be more problems for more complex forms?

They are ordered correctly (by angle) but because the points make a concave polygon you get that result.

Order clockwise is not enough for your concave shape ... a quick Google search should help ...

So you want to order the points to minimise the total path length instead? Not sure what you'd expect to happen with that yellow cluster in the top left though.

@JeremyLakeman not sure if shortest path length is enough either.. I can think of some pointy corners where this would fail as well .. for instance if you look at the numbered sample .. if 39 is just a but further away then it would be skipped and actually never reached/passed at all

You could try and have smaller grained passes: first sort clockwise with a common center. Then make a second pass and use individual centers for smaller batches/groups of points  and swap places where needed  this process you could repeat with smaller group size in further passes .. still just an approximation but might be just enough for your usecase...

I would rather wonder how the top left corner is sorted

I was just thinking that you could test swapping a pair of points in the list, then check if the overall path length was shorter. At least for those 4 points. But you obviously would need enough points on the path to ensure that the shortest overall path, was the shape you wanted.

The solution i found is:

create convex hull
for every missing vertex find the smallest angle for each line on the concave hull
add that vertex to the concave hull with index between the two other points of the found

For efficiency it is possible to find K-Nearest Neighbor before checking the angles for each line on the concave hull. For me i didn't implemented it because in some cases the nearest neighbor are missing the right one if its far away.
C# Code:
 public static List<Vector2> ConcaveHull(List<Vector2> vertices)
 {
     List<Vector2> result = new List<Vector2>(GetConvexHull(vertices));
     List<Vector2> missingVertices = new List<Vector2>(vertices);

     //remove dupes
     missingVertices = missingVertices.Distinct().ToList();
     foreach (Vector2 v in result)
     {
         missingVertices.RemoveAll(x => x == v);
     }

     //find widest angle for 
     for (int i = 0; i < missingVertices.Count; i++)
     {
         //get widest angle
         int index = GetSmallestAngle(missingVertices[i], result);
         //insert on position index + 1 because it is middle position
         result.Insert((index + 1) % result.Count, missingVertices[i]);
     }

     return result;
 }

  private static int GetSmallestAngle(Vector2 checkingVertex, List<Vector2> vertices)
  {
      Dictionary<int, float> distance = new Dictionary<int, float>();

      //set every cos
      for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count; i++)
      {
          distance.Add(i, GetCos(vertices[i], vertices[(i + 1) % vertices.Count], checkingVertex));
      }

      return distance.OrderBy(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault().Key;
  }

  private static float GetCos(Vector2 a, Vector2 b, Vector2 c)
  {
      /* Law of cosines */
      float aPow2 = Mathf.Pow(a.x - c.x, 2) + Mathf.Pow(a.y - c.y, 2);
      float bPow2 = Mathf.Pow(b.x - c.x, 2) + Mathf.Pow(b.y - c.y, 2);
      float cPow2 = Mathf.Pow(a.x - b.x, 2) + Mathf.Pow(a.y - b.y, 2);
      float cos = (aPow2 + bPow2 - cPow2) / (2 * Mathf.Sqrt(aPow2 * bPow2));
      return (float)System.Math.Round(cos, 4);
  }

Source reference:
Convex Hull
Implementation of a fast and efficient concave hull algorithm
